# How to print out text from a text file on multiple lines

Tags: c#

I have a list box that will display some info from a txt file. However, I can't seem to print out the info on different lines. Here's the snippet. The text should be displayed when user presses a button.

```
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Books.txt"))
        {
            String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
            listBox1.Items.Add(line + "\n");
        }
```

There are 10 lines in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `File.ReadAllLines` documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx.

Example of usage is provided at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx

In your example:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("Book.txt");

foreach (var element in lines)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(element);
}
```

You can also do one liner.

```
 listBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("Book.txt")); // tinstaafl's comment
```

Comment: Definitely better than mine.

Comment: It says I need to wait 5 minutes.

Comment: You could simplify the oneliner with listBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("Book.txt"));

Answer (score 0):

`ReadToEnd()` reads everything in the file into one variable.

What you want is `ReadLine()`.

This is one way that should work (though it can probably be done better).

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Books.txt"))
{
    while(true)
    {
        String line = sr.ReadLine();
        if(line==null)
          break;
        listBox1.Items.Add(line + "\n");
    }
}
```

See [the documentation for StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

By using `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` you are putting the whole content of the file in a single string.

To add a Item to the `ListBox` for each line in the file this should work:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Books.txt"))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        listBox1.Items.Add(line);
    }
}
```